# Would rehashing in double hashing also change the primary hash function?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashtable, double-hashing

When you have a collision with the primary hash function in double hashing, you use the secondary hash function.
But if you have a collision with that as well, then you have to rehash, so you double the table size and choose the nearest prime number as the new table size.
Would this also change your primary hash function? For example, if your primary hash function is key mod tableSize and your tableSize was originally 11, and now it is 23, then would that change as well? Because if the hash functions remain the same, you would still have collisions in the same spots.

Comment: "you would still have collisions in the same spots." What makes you think so? When size=11, hash keys of 1 and 12 collide; when size=23, they don't.

Comment: yes it would change in case of the modulo hash function as applying it two times wouldnt change the result. There are some hash function in which the output would change on applying second time.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the new hash will be (x%11+11)%23, i think that what he wants. In this case there will be no collision. But it is not a efficient way of rehashing

Answer (score 1):

> When you have a collision with the primary hash function in double
>   hashing, you use the secondary hash function. But if you have a
>   collision with that as well, then you have to rehash, so you double
>   the table size and choose the nearest prime number as the new table
>   size.

I don't think this is true.

In double hashing,

```
 h(k,i) = h1(k) + i*h2(k)
```

Where h(k,i) is the (i+1)th slot probed for the key. So you successively increase i, so that you hit an empty slot.

You need to rehash, when the load factor exceeds a particular value, and yes when rehashing generally the primary hash function will change, but I think you can get by without it([EDIT: changing the primary hash function]), although it will degrade the performance.

Comment: "but I think you can get by without it" You mean that a rehash is unnecessary? For separate chaining hash-tables, you can get by without rehashing, but for open addressing, I don't think so. However, as rehash is triggered very infrequently, you can implement it in a very stupid (and slow) manner.

Comment: I didn't mean that the rehash is unnecessary, I meant the primary hash function. In the example he can still take the primary hash function to be mod 11 and generate a lot of collissions at the primary level, the performance will be awful but it will still work.

Comment: @jeffrey you are wrong about rehashing can be implemented in stupid manner because a bad rehash function can lead to collisions in original hash function

Answer (score 0):

Practically, for double hashing, I use table size 2^N, and two hash functions, computes values h1(position) and h2(step). Step must be odd, for comply condition

```
gcd(table_sz, step) == 1
```

When this condition complied, probation index iterates **all** cells in the table.

Thereafter, I just iterate table with indexes (pos), (pos+step), (pos + step + step), and
so on, modulo to table_size.

Main loop of program seems like:

```
do {
  pos = (pos + step) & (TAB_SIZE - 1);
} while(table[pos] have collision);
```

See simple example of implementation here:

```
http://olegh.cc.st/src/words.c.txt
```

interesting implementation, when you have TAB_SIZE = 2^16. In this case, you can define variables (pos, step) as unsigned short, and do not need apply mask (TAB_SIZE - 1);
Instead, you just write:

```
pos += step;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my data structures class several weeks ago we were working on Hash Tables. I also ran into this predicament. When I asked my professor, he said that it is not necessary to change the primary hash function upon rehashing. You should be able to still find an empty spot upon rehashing using the technique of open addressing even though you still technically have collisions in the same place. However, he said that usually the primary hash function will be changed to the new modulo and one of the reasons is that it helps prevent clustering of data. So in summary, from what he said its not right or wrong either way, but changing the hash function is the better route to go in order to avoid clustering and collisions at the same places. Hope this helps!